# JSON Array goes crazy

Tags: sql, arrays, output

I have a huge problem with my two lovely JSON-Arrays.

The code is like:

```
else if ($range == "day")   $sqlRangeString = "GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dbtime, '%Y-%c-%e')";

$startdate  = doTimeStamp($startdate);
$enddate    = doTimeStamp($enddate);

  if (isset($consumer_on))
  {
    echo '[';
    $counter = 0;    
    foreach($consumer_name as $consumer_name_value)
    {           
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(loadvalue) AS m1, dbtime, time 
                FROM $consumer_name_value           
                WHERE time >= $startdate 
                AND time <= $enddate 
                $sqlRangeString
                ORDER BY time") or die('#ä');   
    while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {       
      $consumer_value[$counter][0] = $data2['time'];        
      if (!isset($consumer_value[$counter][1]))  $consumer_value[$counter][1] = 0;  
       $consumer_value[$counter][1] =   (float)$consumer_value[$counter][1] +  (float)$data2['m1'];     
      $counter++;      
    }       
    }
    echo json_encode($consumer_value); 
   }

  if (isset($producer_on))
  {
    $ounter = 0;
    if (isset($consumer_on) && ($consumer_on == 1))echo ',';
    foreach($producer_name as $producer_name_value)
    { 
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(power) AS m1, dbtime, time 
                FROM $producer_name_value           
                WHERE time >= $startdate 
                AND time <= $enddate 
                $sqlRangeString
                ORDER BY time") or die('#ää');   ;      

      while ($data3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
      {     
      $producer_value[$counter][0] = $data3['time'];
     if (!isset($producer_value[$counter][1]))  $producer_value[$counter][1] = 0;
      $producer_value[$counter][1] =   $producer_value[$counter][1] +  (float)$data3['m1'];   
      $counter++;
      }      
  }
  echo json_encode($producer_value);    
  }
}

?>
```

My problem is the output :

[image]

Why does the output from the produver_value array has the number in front of each part? How can I remove this?

Comment: if you do an `echo '[';` then where is your `echo ']';` ?

Comment: It is at the end. Approximately 100 lines below. I have chosen only the important lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "array" has a number before each item because the PHP array indexes don't start from 0. You have an associative array instead of a regular one, which makes `json_encode` produce a JSON object instead of an array.

It's possible that this happens because of this typo:

```
$ounter = 0; // should be $counter ?
```

You can use `array_values` to extract the values from the array.

Comment: Thank you so very much! What a fu sh ..